# iOS : Shell script from an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, shell, darwin

I believe, we can run shell scripts from iOS App.
Can someone tell me what is the default shell in iOS and how to call a shell script from iOS App?

(( 
Please consider that I run the script in background. I catch the return value of the script into a variable. (following line is not exact code. Pseudo. Zsh shell is default - I think.) 
myVar=`MyiOSAppBundle\Script.zsh`
))

Regards

Comment: I think first of all you Need a jailbroken device.

Comment: Christian, please see my comment to mbuc91's reply.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in iOS. If you are jailbroken, you may be able to, but otherwise applications are not given admin permissions.

Apple's guide on [The iOS Environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) in which an app lives may give you more insight.

Apple says in their May 2012 document titled "[iOS Security](http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf)":
`Because iOS achieves a reduced attack surface by limiting listening ports and removing unnecessary network utilities such as telnet, shells, or a web server, it doesn’t need firewall software.`

Your question lacks details.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What have you tried?  Are you intending to develop for a jailbroken device or for the App Store?  Please edit your original question or create a new, more complete one.

Comment: I keep my shell script in my iOS App Bundle.  I dont get the script from anywhere else. It is just like I am running any other module. Do I need admin level access for this too? I call C libraries from my iOS App. As in same way, why cant I call a shell script?

Or, is it possible to run shell commands?  Like how we have system() function in C?

Comment: If you are jailbroken (and don't have to run an app within the sandbox invironment), you can use `NSTask` to run a separate process. Even if you import NSTask and get it to work without jailbreaking, Apple will not accept your app into the App Store.