# Executing shell commands for iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstask

How do I execute shell commands for iOS app in Xcode(it does not support NSTask.h as the app is sandboxed)?

Comment: I'd usually mark this as a duplicate of [iOS : Shell script from an iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645294/ios-shell-script-from-an-ios-app), but that question is almost 10 years old.

Comment: Yes ,I was hoping for an alternative but looks like it isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no (public) shell available, and also no (public) high-level API to run external commands. This is a deliberate restriction of iOS.

You might be able to use low-level POSIX/Mach APIs like `posix_spawn` to start an executable that you bundle, though. But even if you manage to do that, it's likely that Apple will reject your App Store submission if you do that.